# Sending message from slave to master (SPI)

Tags: spi

I'm trying to send a message from slave to master using SPI (I'm using only one STM board) and so far nothing I tried has worked. AFAIK for the slave to send data to master, the master has to initiate communication first by sending clock signals, and dummy bytes.

1. To be able to send data from slave to master, is Full Duplex is a must (for purpose of Master to send dummy bytes while simultanously receiving bytes)?
2. I'm not sure what function should I use with the slave, and what is the order of function calls.

I tried using HAL_SPI_TransmitRecieve() in Master side but that didn't work because once using it, it seems to automatically transmit and receving whatever is coming from slave side (only '\0' string).

Im attaching code block:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hw_main.h"

extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

#define SPI_1_MASTER &hspi1
#define SPI_2_SLAVE &hspi2
#define UART_DEBUG &huart3
#define PACKET_SIZE 1
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

int flag_1=0;
int flag_2=0;


void ex1(){
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
    uint8_t msg[BUFF_SIZE]="AbraKadabra";
    uint8_t spi1_buff[BUFF_SIZE]={0};

    uint8_t spi2_buff[BUFF_SIZE]={0};
    HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(SPI_2_SLAVE, spi2_buff, BUFF_SIZE); 


    HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_1_MASTER, msg, BUFF_SIZE,HAL_MAX_DELAY); 
//until here everything works well! but from this line on nothing I 
tried seems to work.


    while(1){
        if (flag_2){
            HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(SPI_1_MASTER, spi1_buff, BUFF_SIZE);
            HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_2_SLAVE, spi2_buff,BUFF_SIZE,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            flag_2=0;
// when reaching here, spi1_buff contains only null characters.
        } 
        if (flag_1){
            HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_DEBUG, spi1_buff, BUFF_SIZE, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            flag_1=0;
        }
     }
 }
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi){
    if (hspi== SPI_2_SLAVE){
        flag_2=1;
    }
    if (hspi== SPI_1_MASTER){
        flag_1=1;
    }
}
```

SPI initializations:

```
    void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
      hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
      hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
      hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE;
      hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
      hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
      hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
      hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_OUTPUT;
      hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
      hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
      hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
      hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
      hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
      hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
      hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
      if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

    }
    /* SPI2 init function */
    void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
      hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
      hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
      hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE;
      hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
      hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
      hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
      hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
      hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
      hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
      hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
      hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
      hspi2.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
      hspi2.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

    }
```

Comment: You understand correctly.
in SPI the master is responsible for providing the clock(clk). 
Could you please clarify what is the master device and what is the slave? are they both STM boards?
Also sharing your code(especially the part of the SPI driver initialization) would allow to better understand where is the issue

Comment: @kipo, both master and slave are situated on same stm32f746zg board (sounds weird, I know). Also I added code block to the original message.

Comment: Did you check what status is returned from the calls to HAL_SPI_Receive_IT and HAL_SPI_Transmit?

Comment: yes, both are HAL_OK